# using filter filter in for-loop with in-operator on arry

Tags: filter, twig

as

```
{% for key, t in array1 if key in array2) %}
```

doen't work in twig 3.x i switched to

```
{% for key, t in array1|filter(key => key in array2) %}
```

but with this syntax the keys in array2 are not found and the for does not display them.

array2 dumps as

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "19" [1]=> string(2) "20" [2]=> string(2) "21" [3]=> string(2) "22" [4]=> string(2) "68" [5]=> string(2) "69" [6]=> string(2) "70" [7]=> string(2) "73" }
```

if i apply an if-statement in the loop like

```
{% for key, t in array1 %}
    {% if key in array2 %}
```

it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you want to pass the key you will also need to pass the value to the arrow function:

```
{% for k, v in array1|filter((v,k) => k in array2) %}
    {{ k }} -> {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#f16cd196e3)

---

note: You can't swap `(v,k)` around. The first argument passed is supposed to be the value, the second the key. If you switch them around, the snippet no longer works. <s>This could be a bug</s>

note2: This work as intended and is documented almost at the bottom of the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html) for this filter

> The arrow function also receives the key as a second argument: